# How to retrieve radio button value from database using C#

Tags: c#, radio-button, groupbox

I have a group box contains radio buttons eg.

> o Level 1
>
> o Level 2

How can I load value from database and check radio botton on my GUI?

```
private void button_clone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * from PPAPdatabase where [PSW ID]=" + txt_c_PSW_ID.Text + "";
        OleDbDataReader dr = null;
        dr = command.ExecuteReader();                
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            comboBox_PPAP.Text = (dr["Reason"].ToString());
            checkedListBox_prodline.Text = (dr["Production Line"].ToString());                    
            checkedListBox_owner.Text = (dr["Owner"].ToString());              
            txt_comment.Text = (dr["Comment"].ToString());                                                          
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " + ex.Message,
                "Important Note",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of UI, windows forms, asp.net?

Comment: What kind of data is it that you are trying to bind the radio button with? Is it a bit, string, integer column?

Comment: @BrianMains windows from application

Comment: @DrSchizo I have a column named PPAP level, and I just save the text of the levels in that colum.

Comment: Can you post how the data looks like? Do you want the radio checked if the column has anything in it, i.e. is NOT an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your radio button is called `radioButton1` and the column your referring to stores values as either `1` or `0` then you would do:

```
radioButton1.Checked = row["PPAP"].ToString() == "1";
```